# How to get data from Firebase on document ready

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have devloped these firebase script, and I want some help  to get like count from firebase data when document ready.

Second qousttion,How to make the button (like/dislike) can click once(want the user can only trigger it only once)?

Html

```js
// store the main Firebase URL
var firebaseURL = 'https://app-api-163321.firebaseio.com/like-button/';

// update the likeCounts shown in a <span> beside each blogpost
var postDivs = document.querySelectorAll('.post');

for (var i = 0; i < postDivs.length; i++) {
    var postID = postDivs[i].id;
    var numLikes = getLikeCount(postID);
}

// this function grabs the likeCount for a particular post from the Firebase
function getLikeCount(postID) {
    var thisPostRef = new Firebase(firebaseURL + postID + '/like-count/');
    thisPostRef.once('value', function (snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.val()) {
            document.querySelector('#' + postID + ' .like-count').innerHTML = snapshot.val() + ' likes';
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    });
}

function likePost(id) {
    var postRef = new Firebase(firebaseURL + id);
    // get current number of likes here, so we can increment if any exist
    postRef.child('like-count').once('value', function (snapshot) {
        var currentLikes = snapshot.val() ? snapshot.val() : 0;
        postRef.update({
            'postID': id,
            'like-count': currentLikes + 1

        }, function (error) {
                console.log(error);
        });
        getLikeCount(id);
    });
}

function dlikePost(id) {
    console.log('running likePost() for post ID:', id);
    var postRef = new Firebase(firebaseURL + id);

    // get current number of likes here, so we can increment if any exist
    postRef.child('like-count').once('value', function (snapshot) {
        console.log('snapshot.val():', snapshot.val());
        var currentLikes = snapshot.val() ? snapshot.val() : 0;
        console.log('currentLikes:', currentLikes);
        postRef.update({
            'postID': id,
            'like-count': currentLikes - 1

        }, function (error) {
            if (error) {
                console.log('Data could not be saved:' + error);
            } else {
                console.log('Data saved successfully');
            }
        });

        getLikeCount(id);
    });
}
```

```html
<script src='https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/2.2.7/firebase.js'></script>


<div class="gpc" id="p72561979729402801623">
    <a class="btn btn-success  like bl1" data-id="13796" href="#" onclick="likePost('p72561979729402801623');">like</a>
    <div class="like-count bl2" />
    <a class="btn btn-danger  dislike bl3" href="#" onclick="dlikePost('p72561979729402801623');">dilike</a>
</div>
```

Are there anyways to do it?

https://jsfiddle.net/vj8regwy/

Comment: better to listen for realtime updates to get this data.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT (added code for disabling the buttons client-side):**
You should get the idea and can finish it on your own

```
    <script>
    // store the main Firebase URL
    var firebaseURL = 'https://app-api-163321.firebaseio.com/like-button/';

    function updateLikeCount(postID, count) {
        document.querySelector('#' + postID + ' .like-count').innerHTML = count + ' likes';
    }

    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
        var postDivs = document.querySelectorAll('.post');

        for (var i = 0; i < postDivs.length; i++) {
            getLikeCount(postDivs[i].id, updateLikeCount);
        }
    });

    // this function grabs the likeCount for a particular post from the Firebase
    function getLikeCount(postID, callback) {
        var thisPostRef = new Firebase(firebaseURL + postID + '/like-count/');
        return thisPostRef.once('value', function (snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.val()) {
                callback(postID, snapshot.val());

            } else {
                callback(postID, 0);
            }
        });
    }

    function likePost(postID) {
        if (localStorage.getItem('liked') === "true") {
            return false;
        }

        var postRef = new Firebase(firebaseURL + postID);
        // get current number of likes here, so we can increment if any exist
        postRef.child('like-count').once('value', function (snapshot) {
            var currentLikes = snapshot.val() ? snapshot.val() : 0;
            postRef.update({
                'postID': postID,
                'like-count': currentLikes + 1

            }, function (error) {
                console.log(error);
            });
            localStorage.setItem('liked', true);
            document.getElementById('btn-like').disabled = true;
            getLikeCount(postID, updateLikeCount);
        });
    }

    function dlikePost(postID) {
        if (localStorage.getItem('disliked') === "true") {
            return false;
        }

        console.log('running likePost() for post ID:', postID);
        var postRef = new Firebase(firebaseURL + postID);

        // get current number of likes here, so we can increment if any exist
        postRef.child('like-count').once('value', function (snapshot) {
            console.log('snapshot.val():', snapshot.val());
            var currentLikes = snapshot.val() ? snapshot.val() : 0;
            console.log('currentLikes:', currentLikes);
            postRef.update({
                'postID': postID,
                'like-count': currentLikes - 1

            }, function (error) {
                if (error) {
                    console.log('Data could not be saved:' + error);
                } else {
                    console.log('Data saved successfully');
                }
            });
            localStorage.setItem('disliked', true);
            document.getElementById('btn-dislike').disabled = true;
            getLikeCount(postID, updateLikeCount);
        });
    }
</script>
<script src='https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/2.2.7/firebase.js'></script>

<div class="gpc post" id="p72561979729402801623">
    <a class="btn btn-success  like bl1" data-id="13796" id="btn-like" href="#" onclick="likePost('p72561979729402801623');">Like</a>
    <span class="like-count bl2"></span>
    <a class="btn btn-danger  dislike bl3" id="btn-dislike" href="#" onclick="dlikePost('p72561979729402801623');">Dislike</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer .
Maybe There is a mistake in the function dlikePost ( 'postID': id,  ) ;the correct is ('postID': postID,).

tell me,How to make the button (like/dislike) can click once ?

Comment: Well, to make it really secure, you should implement this logic server side. Otherwise, you could do it just client side maybe using localStorage?